# Tablix: Repeat header rows on each page not working in SSRS 2008R2

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with a tablix that has row headers. I want to repeat the headers on each page, so I activated the flag `Repeat header columns on each page`. I have also set the propertys in `Advanced Mode` in the Groups panel and set the follwing options:

1) Set the `RepeatOnNewPage` property to `True`

2) `KeepWithGroup` property is set to `After`

3) `Fixed data` set to `True`.

I have also verified the xml which looks fine.

After setting all these properties still I am not getting the  header in some pages.

I somewhere read that it was the bug in the SQL Server 2008. And that it is corrected in 2008R2. But it looks like that it not so, because I am using 2008R2 and the problem is still exist.

Comment: This isn't a programming question to me. Or is it ? I don't see any code...

Comment: When you export report to Excel, the problem remains?

Comment: No it is working fine with Excel.This problem is occuring when i try to export it to PDF

Comment: I only set flag `Repeat header columns on each page` in tablix properties and export to PDF was successful. I'm using SSRS 2008R2 SP1.

Comment: Share that PDF output.